# Skip part of superclass __init__?

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a class which subclass another. I would like to skip a part of the initialization process, for example:

```
class Parent:
    __init__(self, a, b, c, ...):
        # part I want to keep:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        ...
        # part I want to skip, which is memory and time consuming
        # but unnecessary for the subclass:
        self.Q = AnotherClass()

class Child(Parent):
    __init__(self):
        #a part of the parent initialization process, then other stuff
```

The two solutions I've come up with are:

- Make an abstract class parent of the `Parent` class which wouldn't include the unwanted part of the initialization for the `Child`, or
- Duplicate just the part of the initialization of the parent that I want in the child

Which is best, or are there better methods?

Comment: Logically it seems more in keeping with OO principles to create a base class which has only the stuff you want to use in every instance (as you suggest) and inherit from that. This can cause unwanted complexity in your code, but probably still preferable to doing a weird hack I would personally feel.

Comment: Is the parent class under your control, or is it a 3rd party class to you?

Comment: @snapshoe It's under my control

Comment: Really, `Child` and `ParentWithAnotherClass` would be separate subclasses of `ParentWithoutAnotherClass` (which may or may not be abstract).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about wrapping creation of `Q` into private method, and overriding that method in subclass?

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, ...):
        # part I want to keep:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self._init_q()

    def _init_q():
        self.Q = AnotherClass()

class Child(Parent):
    def _init_q(self):
        pass  # do not init q when creating subclass
```

It's not a cleanest approach, since if `Child` does not need `Q` either it shouldn't be a child of Parent, or maybe `AnotherClass` is misplaced (maybe it should be injected to methods which needs it) but it solves your issue without changing any of class interfaces.